# How can I write a DQL for these entities?

Tags: php, codeigniter, doctrine, doctrine-orm, dql

I have entities seen as DB screenshot:

You can see the screenshot here-> http://imageshack.us/photo/my-images/830/asdsasda.jpg/

I want to bring an object array of TnModuleItem by giving a TnRegion parameter.

How can i write in DQL to bring this query.

Edit: I want to write a model like this:

```
public function get_module_items_by_region_id($region_id){
// code comes here
return $tnModuleItemsObj //TnModuleItemsObject
}
```

Comment: I don't really get your question, what is the exact result you want to retrieve? Please edit your post.

Comment: just edited. hope you got it.

Comment: Where is the function get_module_items_by_region_id part of? An entity? Do you have relations?

Comment: I have entities: TnModuleItem, TnPage, TnRegion, TnPageRegion, TnRegionModuleItem etc.. Just want to write a model function to take a region parameter and to give related module items.

Answer (score 0):

And if you try something like:

```
 <?php
 public function get_module_items_by_region_id($region_id){
     $query = $em->createQuery('SELECT i FROM \namespace\TnRegionModuleItem as i WHERE i.regionId = :region_id');
     $query->setParameter('region_id', $region_id)

     return $query->getResult()
 }     

 ?>
```

Offcourse you should get your entitymanager somewhere from and put in the variable $em, in my case I use the Bisna 'glue' for Zend Framework and I retrieve it by the Zend_Registry but that could be different in your case.

With the result value you can foreach your module items and every element is a tnModuleItem object.

Good luck!

Comment: i'm using Doctrine and Codeigniter. It gives this error as i wait: TnRegionModuleItem has no field or association named regionId

Comment: i must setup an associaton TnRegionModuleItem with TnPageRegion and after that TnRegion. what can i do for it?

Comment: You don't need to set up a ascocation for this particular query but it would be nice as well to set up a manyToMany relation with the tn_region_module_item as a jointable. You proberly getting the error because I just guessed what the regionId field is in the where part of your query. Please post your complete entity class and I will edit my post with a more complete example.

Comment: added. thanks for your all support. waiting you now and trying another options also :)

Comment: trying this: SELECT mi FROM TnRegionModuleItem rmi, TnModuleItem mi JOIN rmi.pageRegion pr WHERE pr.region = 3 giving me this error: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 't1_.page_region_id' in 'on clause''...

Comment: Your query looks okay but i'm not sure about the ascocations. It's a good idea to print the native SQL: $query->getSQL() on a Doctrine query object. In order to make my above example work you have to add a private variable names regionId to your tnRegionModuleItem class with @Column(type="integer", name="page_region_id") but your approach looks cleaner.

Answer (score 0):

OK. I solved problem with this:

```
            $query = $this->em->createQuery('SELECT rmi, mi FROM TnRegionModuleItem rmi JOIN rmi.moduleItem mi JOIN rmi.pageRegion pr JOIN pr.region r WHERE r.id = :regionid');
```

must select a root entity.